# MouseEnter/MouseLeave issues with showing absolutely positioned element

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, jquery-hover

http://screencast.com/t/2KncBbiroMz

The above link more accurately shows you the issue I am having. The hover works however if you hover slowly over the LI element then the link that appears disappears right as you hover the link.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="stats">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span16">
                <ul class="user-stats">
                    <li id="class-points">
                        <span class="stats-content-container">
                            <span class="class-name"><%= class_room_name %></span><br />
                            <span class="large-headline"><%= total_game_points %></span> <span class="smaller-desc">points</span>
                        </span>
                        <a class="edit-class-name" href="#edit-class-name-modal" data-toggle="modal">edit name</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
​$(function(){
   $('ul.user-stats li#class-points').mouseenter(function() {
      $('a.edit-class-name', this).stop(true, true).show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
      $('a.edit-class-name', this).stop(true, true).hide();
    }); 
});​​​
```

I even tried this with a pure CSS solution and I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your edit link absolutely positioned? If so, there may be a 1px gap between the li and the anchor. Would need to see the html to be certain.

Comment: That was it! The edit link was (from the top of the LI) 66px, I adjusted it to be 65px and it fixed it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The issues seems to be that there is a gap between `stats-content-container` and `edit-class-name`, so the mouse actually leaves `class-points` at some points before hovering over `edit-class-name`.

Maybe you can try putting your mouseleave on a parent element (maybe `<ul class="user-stats">`? hard to say without seeing the actualy html/css) that encompasses that entire section.